# How to handle spelling mistakes in UnigramTagger in nltk python?

Tags: python, nltk, fuzzywuzzy

I am doing Named Entity Recognition using python nltk library.I am using `UnigramTagger` to custom tag tokens.And its happening perfectly fine.
The problem is the tagger *exactly tags* to words that I mention in my model.With any spelling mistake,it fails to find the word.
How do I solve this problem?
I liked how `fuzzywuzzy` allows ratio search but don't know if the same functionality is provided by any nltk tagger .Need some help here.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct spellings before Named Entity Recognition. You can do this from following url..

[spell checker](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)